# Share facebook link does not work on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

When open share facebook link on mobile browsers, it will redirect https://`www.facebook.com`/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p... to https://`m.facebook.com`/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p... and show the following:

[image]

I tried to add `m2w&` into share link like `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p`, but still doesn't work and got as same response as the screenshot. The same code works on desktop browsers.

How to fix it? It should be a normal issue but I can't get solution from google. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The sharer.php script is outdated; you should rather implement the Share dialog using current methods: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog If you want to keep it plain&simple, you can use the URL redirect version. But especially for mobile users, you might consider using the JS SDK, so that you can trigger the special mobile version (iframe overlay) of the dialog in these cases.

Comment: thanks for the solution, any other solution works for php function?

Comment: Again: _“If you want to keep it plain&simple, you can use the URL redirect version”_.

Answer (score 0):

Change the link from `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p...` to

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

then change the parameters as need.